# Case Statement On Two Conditions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, case

Can i add these both together to work as one, the user can select valid for country 1 or 2 and BOTH so i need these to work together 
if possible
and when user selects both i need it to show both measurements

I CANNOT CREATE A NEW TABLE so i need essentially column that will populate based on what country and unit price base will be sufficient

```
,CASE 
    WHEN bd.Validforcountry = 1 and BD.UnitpriceBase = 1
        THEN '100 ml'
    WHEN bd.Validforcountry = 1 and BD.UnitpriceBase = 2
        THEN '1 l'
    WHEN bd.Validforcountry = 1 and BD.UnitpriceBase = 3
        THEN '100 g'
    WHEN bd.Validforcountry = 1 and  BD.UnitpriceBase = 4
        THEN '1 Kg'
    WHEN bd.Validforcountry = 1 and BD.UnitpriceBase = 5
        THEN '750 ml'
    ELSE BD.UnitpriceBase
    END AS 'Unit price Declaration'


,CASE 
    WHEN bd.Validforcountry = 2 and BD.UnitpriceBase = 1
        THEN '100 ml'
    WHEN bd.Validforcountry = 2 and BD.UnitpriceBase = 2
        THEN '1 l'
    WHEN bd.Validforcountry = 2 and BD.UnitpriceBase = 3
        THEN '100 g'
    WHEN bd.Validforcountry = 2 and  BD.UnitpriceBase = 4
        THEN '1 Kg'
    WHEN bd.Validforcountry = 2 and BD.UnitpriceBase = 5
        THEN '750 ml'
    ELSE BD.UnitpriceBase
    END AS 'Unit price Declaration'
```

Comment: Hardcoding those values in cases seems like a bad idea. You should create an additional table linking countries and values.

Comment: a Temportary table or ?

Comment: @X.L.Ant ^^ Temporary

Comment: Is there ever just UK and IRE? Or should you think of a more open design allowing several countries in future?

Comment: @Shnugo no only Uk And IRE

Comment: What is the question? I don't see what you actually want to do. There are just to identical case expressions.?

Comment: @StefanSteinegger look properly there two different cases the second one will have different Values but for now that is all you need 
valid for country 1 is uk 2 is ireland

Comment: Ok. And they are used in ... ? A query, view, stored procedure, what? When in a query, as two different columns or in different queries? ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating complex `CASE WHEN`, just create a new table, so you can select the correct value with a simple JOIN. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE UnitPriceDeclaration
(
    Country int,
    UnitPriceBase int,
    UnitPriceDeclaration varchar(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (Country, UnitPriceBase)
);
```

This way, you can write your query like this (dummy joins, I don't know anything about your other tables):

```
SELECT t1.someField, 
       t2.someOtherField, 
       t1.UnitPriceBase, 
       t2.Country, 
       upd.UnitPriceDeclaration
FROM oneTable t1,
INNER JOIN anotherTable t2 ON ...
INNER JOIN UnitPriceDeclaration upd ON upd.Country = t2.Country AND upd.UnitPriceBase = t1.UnitPriceBase -- maybe LEFT JOIN
WHERE...
```

This allows you to keep flexibility and add/change as many countries, UPB or UPD as you want, without anything to change other than data. Using `CASE WHEN` as you do, you would have to change your code each time something changes (potentially in more than one place).

Your edit advocates for this solution. See all those repeated values ?

So let's say you want to display two UPD, one for UK and one for IRE. You just have to do something like this:

```
SELECT t1.someField, 
       t2.someOtherField, 
       t1.UnitPriceBase, 
       t2.Country, 
       upduk.UnitPriceDeclaration as UPD_UK,
       updire.UnitPriceDeclaration as UPD_IRE
FROM oneTable t1,
INNER JOIN UnitPriceDeclaration upduk ON upd.UnitPriceBase = t1.UnitPriceBase AND upd.Country = 1
INNER JOIN UnitPriceDeclaration updire ON upd.UnitPriceBase = t1.UnitPriceBase AND upd.Country = 2
WHERE...
```

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean, do you want to output one column displaying UK UPD alogng with a column displaying IRE UPD ?

Comment: no Ant i want one column but dependant on what the user selects for {@validcountry} it will change the measurements
but be aware the user can select both so it would then need to link both of them together

Comment: your case table creation was helpful but i need to do it this was as requested by the previous developer

Comment: im not allowed to create tables at my work or even temp tables so please provide another option

Comment: If you don't create a table you are introducing _technical debt_

Comment: If you can't create any table you seem to be kind of stuck with what you have right now.

Comment: @X.L.Ant please look at my edit i cannot create tables so i need a hard coded case statement

Comment: I agree with you, I added my comment after the edit. There's no nice solution without creating a table, so yes, you'll have to hardcode, as you already did. I don't know what can be done further. But Nick is right, this introduces a technical debt someone will have to pay for in the future.

Comment: Could you use a declared table variable? You can use the same logic without physical table creation...